# SimpleXML root node prefix php

Tags: php, xml, xml-simple

I'm trying to create XML with php:
this is true XML

```
<p:FatturaElettronica versione="FPA12" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPA12" >
 <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
  <DatiTrasmissione>
   <IdTrasmittente>
    <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
    <IdCodice>01234567890</IdCodice>
   </IdTrasmittente>
   <ProgressivoInvio>00001</ProgressivoInvio>
   <FormatoTrasmissione>FPA12</FormatoTrasmissione>
   <CodiceDestinatario>AAAAAA</CodiceDestinatario>
  </DatiTrasmissione>
```

My code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<p:FatturazioneElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" />');
$xml->addAttribute("versione","FPA12");
$xml->addAttribute("xmlns:xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$FatturaElettronicaHeader = $xml->addChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader');
$DatiTrasmissione=$FatturaElettronicaHeader->addChild('DatiTrasmissione');
$IdTrasmittente=$DatiTrasmissione->addChild('IdTrasmittente');
$IdTrasmittente->addChild('IdPaese', 'IT');
$IdTrasmittente->addChild('IdCodice','01234567890');

$ProgressivoInvio=$DatiTrasmissione->addChild('ProgressivoInvio', '00001');
$FormatoTrasmissione=$DatiTrasmissione->addChild('DatiTrasmissione', 'FPA12');
$CodiceDestinatario=$DatiTrasmissione->addChild('CodiceDestinatario', 'AAAAAA');
```

in my xml file i have prefix p: in every tag.

i need to have prefix p in root node (p:FatturaElettronica).

I don't know how to do it.

```
<p:FatturazioneElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPA12">
 <p:FatturaElettronicaHeader>
   <p:DatiTrasmissione>
    <p:IdTrasmittente>
     <p:IdPaese>IT</p:IdPaese>
     <p:IdCodice>01234567890</p:IdCodice>
    </p:IdTrasmittente>
    <p:ProgressivoInvio>00001</p:ProgressivoInvio>
   <p:DatiTrasmissione>FPA12</p:DatiTrasmissione>
   <p:CodiceDestinatario>AAAAAA</p:CodiceDestinatario>
 </p:DatiTrasmissione>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with SimpleXML is that if you don't specify the namespace of an element when adding it, it assumes the namespace of the parent node (hence the `p:`).  To add it to the default namespace (i.e. without a prefix) there are a couple of things you will need to change.

First is to add a default namespace declaration at the root element...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<p:FatturazioneElettronica 
      xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
      xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" 
      xmlns="http://dummy.com" />');
```

I've just added is as `xmlns="http://dummy.com"` near the end.

Then when adding the first element to the document, add this to the newly defined default namespace...

```
$FatturaElettronicaHeader = $xml->addChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader', 
            null, 'http://dummy.com');
```

Comment: I don't understand what I have to change, sorry but I'm inexperienced on this topic

Comment: Sorry for the delay - have you got it sorted now?

Comment: No, I don't understand what I have to change in my code.

Comment: If you look at the lines of code in the answer and compare them with the lines you already have, you should see the differences.

Comment: I have to get only those namespaces

Comment: If i write your code the namespace it's correct, but i my situation i don't have your namespace. i don't understand which namespace I have to put in the tag FatturaElettronicaHeader for don't repeat "p:"